# HelpPage Dont find View after routing areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-web-api-routing

I launched the API Help Page for the my web API project.

Now the question is that after Routing on other Areas my Help page can not be found index.cshtml. This is global.asax code and I posted a picture of the error message

```
protected void Application_Start()
   {
       GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
       FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
       RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
       BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

       AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

       MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true; /*Version Discloser 5 in 10 point*/
       //Infrastructure.ConnectionStringEncryption.EncryptConnString();
       //GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new HandleAntiforgeryTokenErrorAttribute() { ExceptionType = typeof(HttpAntiForgeryException) });




   }
```

[image]

My helppage controller code:

```
    public class HelpController : Controller
{
    private const string ErrorViewName = "Error";

    public HelpController()
        : this(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
    {
    }

    public HelpController(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        Configuration = config;
    }

    public HttpConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.DocumentationProvider = Configuration.Services.GetDocumentationProvider();
        return View(Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer().ApiDescriptions);
    }

    public ActionResult Api(string apiId)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(apiId))
        {
            HelpPageApiModel apiModel = Configuration.GetHelpPageApiModel(apiId);
            if (apiModel != null)
            {
                return View(apiModel);
            }
        }

        return View(ErrorViewName);
    }

    public ActionResult ResourceModel(string modelName)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(modelName))
        {
            ModelDescriptionGenerator modelDescriptionGenerator = Configuration.GetModelDescriptionGenerator();
            ModelDescription modelDescription;
            if (modelDescriptionGenerator.GeneratedModels.TryGetValue(modelName, out modelDescription))
            {
                return View(modelDescription);
            }
        }

        return View(ErrorViewName);
    }
}
```

And my help page view is here:

[image: helppage view]

Comment: Where is your Help Page stored ?

Comment: With HelpPage name In Areas

Comment: post your helpcontroller, and help view location

Comment: I edited my question and posted controller

Comment: try with below url :
"yourlocalhost/HelpPage/Help"

Comment: if your controller is inside area, you can not access directly else it will try to find it in controller outside of area. so you can try with this url :
"yourlocalhost/HelpPage/Help"
or you need to set URL configuration without area name.

Comment: Unfortunately ,it does not work.
As you can see in my global.asax file I have enabled routing in areas so there is a problem with this .if disabled routing help page will be available.

Comment: Actually issue is in your Global file register statements ordering. you need to register first all area before registering routes. set register area on the top and then above url as i mentioned. it will definietly work